# How to ignore null values in sum in hive

Tags: hive

I am having a table in hive with below values

```
ID  value
1
1

ID  value
1
1   2
```

while doing sum i need the output as

```
select id,sum(val) from table group by id;
```

first required output

```
id sum
1
```

Second table Output

```
id sum
1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

In math default `2+0=2` so its anyway going to work .Don't worry about this `hive`will be default will take care this.

```
hive> create table first (Id int,value int);
OK
Time taken: 3.895 seconds
hive> select * from first;
OK
1       2
1       NULL
hive> select id, sum(value) as sum from first group by id;
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 4 seconds 610 msec
OK
1       2
Time taken: 83.483 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter out rows with null sum, use `having`:

```
select id, sum(value) from table group by id having sum(value) is not null;
```