# Average Function with not null columns - Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, aggregate-functions, hiveql

I want to calculate an average for the first 3 years income which is not NULL for eg :

```
employee id    2016  2015 2014 2013  2012  2011  2010
      1         100  NULL 200   50   10     50    50
```

average should be on 100 + 200 + 50 / 3

```
employee id    2016  2015 2014 2013  2012   2011 2010
      2        NULL  100  NULL  50    NULL  25   100
```

average should be 100 + 50 + 25 / 3

Comment: Did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721920/how-to-ignore-null-values-in-sum-in-hive

Comment: is the data stored in the table that way? or is this the result of a query?

Comment: The data is stored in above format

Answer (score 1):

Get one row per year with `union all`. Then rank the rows with `row_number` function so that non-null rows would be ranked first. Then get the average of first 3 rows.

```
select employee_id,avg(income)
from (select employee_id,yr,income
      ,row_number() over(partition by employee_id order by cast((income is not null) as int) desc,yr desc) as rnum 
      from (select employee_id,2016 as yr,`2016` as income from tbl 
            union all
            select employee_id,2015 as yr,`2015` as income from tbl
            union all
            select employee_id,2014 as yr,`2014` as income from tbl
            union all
            select employee_id,2013 as yr,`2013` as income from tbl
            union all
            select employee_id,2012 as yr,`2012` as income from tbl
            union all
            select employee_id,2011 as yr,`2011` as income from tbl
            union all
            select employee_id,2010 as yr,`2010` as income from tbl
           ) t
      ) t
where rnum <= 3
group by employee_id
```

- When 2 columns have values, the result would be (val1+val2)/2.
- When only one column has a value, the result would be that column.
- When all columns have a `null` value, `null` is returned.